# 301 Redirect only is a certain parameter is not existing

Tags: .htaccess

How can I redirect a page to another one except when a certain parameter is passed?

For example:

- `example.org/page` should redirect to `example.org/campaign/index.html`.
- But `example.org/page?bypass=yes` should not redirect as it contains the `bypass=yes` info.

This is my try:

```
redirect 301 /page^(.*)$ http://example.org/campaign/index.html
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(?:^|&)bypass=yes(?:&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^page campaign/index.html [NC,L,R=301]
```